# concatenating mp3 files or joining mp3 files using java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

We would like to concatenate/merge/join mp3 files seamlessly using "java" in any environment. We are trying the following options at the moment ( please let us know any other options):

1. Using JMF -- ruled out as it supported only in windows http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/reference/faqs/index.html
2. Using tritinous , jlayer and Lame combination.

Please let us know thoughts and the links those mention about concatenate/merge/join mp3 files using option 2.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple QuickTime for Java](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/qtjava/getstarted.html) would be one alternative