# Combine two wave files to create a single smoother wave file in java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I have a requirement of joining two audio waves so that the final output audio wave should have a smoother meeting point. I meant at the joining point lets' say for 10 seconds the first audio should start fading out and the other audio starts picking up.

I have already been able to concatenate the two audio files and produce a single output but the output wave file has a abrupt change at the meeting point.

I am looking forward to some code in java (i.e. the crossfading should happen through java code without playing the files in any audio player And just to mention that I am not targeting the android solution.) or please point me to any helpful link demonstrating how to do the same.

Comment: It would help to see the code that is joining the files now

Comment: sorry, won't be able to share the code as right now my laptop on which I work upon is not with me... For now I can just tell you that the code uses an output stream where I just keep writing the bytes from first wave file and then the second wave file.

Comment: Are these raw audio bytes or compressed mp3 bytes?

Comment: raw audio bytes.. sorry for intermittent delayed reply...

Comment: Hmm, what happens when you just add the bytes together?

Comment: the abrupt changes in sound at the joining point

Comment: No, that's concatenation.  Was asking about adding two raw bytes to form one byte.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73641/discussion-between-doped-dude-and-candiedorange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is called crossfading.  Corssfade means to slowly bring up the volume of the new song while slowly bringing the volume of the old one down.  For a time both can be heard.

You might want to look at these:

[java sound fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471112/java-sound-fade-out)

[concatenating mp3 files or joining mp3 files using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729824/concatenating-mp3-files-or-joining-mp3-files-using-java?rq=1)

Comment: "java sound found out" was helpful but a link "OpenJava Sound Demo" present in the solution seems broken, so I was not able to understand the solution completely. Can you point me to some code/URL demonstrating the same.